# how to get the bouding box dimension when using the object capture api in iOS17 after detecting the object

Tags: arkit, realitykit, ios17

I want to get the bounding box when this api detect the object from ObjectCaptureView, but I do not find the api from api document, do not know how to make it.
this is the api
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/objectcaptureview

I want to get the dimension of bounding box about the object, so I can do something about that value